# Set Document Root for site?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I have a CentoOS 6.7 server set up with Apache.  I can confirm it is working correctly - say the machine's IP is 123.456.789.123, I can navigate to http://123.456.789.123/~myUserName/ and get webpages in my home/myUserName/public_html/ folder to load. However, when I just try http://123.456.789.123 I get an error page (specifically, it's /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi).  How do I configure this server to show files from my public_html directory when a user simply navigates to http://123.456.789.123?

Comment: Funny you should use the terms DocumentRoot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the document root in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

[image]